# openai js modules starts hundreds of preflight checks

Tags: ionic-framework, openai-api

I'm trying to do some tests in my Ionic app with openai. I already made it work with axios, but I thought in trying openai npm module to see if there is any performance increase.

As I'm initially doing performance tests, I have enabled the 'dangerouslyAllowBrowser' option.
But when I try to make the first request, openai module opens literally hundred of preflight requests and keeps opening them idefinetely:

[image]

This was before I stopped the process, or the number would increase indefinetely. Any idea why this is ?

I have created the Api object this way:

```
    this.openai = new OpenAI({ "apiKey": apiKey, dangerouslyAllowBrowser: true });
```

the openai request is this:

```
(...)
initialConversation: any[] = [
    { role: 'system', content: 'My ChatGPT prompt.' },
]
context: any = {
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: this.initialConversation,
};

(...)

let ctx: any = this.context;
ctx.messages = this.initialConversation;
this.addMessage(ctx, 'my 2nd message');
let response = await this.openai.chat.completions.create(ctx);

(...)
```